# JNI API call resulting in JNI_EVERSION error

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface

I am having troubles getting the Java Native Interface (JNI) running on my OS. My minimal working example (derived from [here](http://hildstrom.com/projects/jni/index.html) and adjusted for my system) returns a version error, **JNI_EVERSION (-3)**, upon calling `JNI_CreateJavaVM()`. My c-file looks like

```
// hello_world.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <jni.h>

JNIEnv *create_vm(JavaVM **jvm)
{
  JNIEnv* env;
  JavaVMInitArgs args;
  JavaVMOption options;
  args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_8;
  args.nOptions = 1;
  options.optionString = "-Djava.class.path=./";
  args.options = &options;
  args.ignoreUnrecognized = 0;
  int rv;
  rv = JNI_CreateJavaVM(jvm, (void**)&env, &args);
  if (rv < 0 || !env)
      printf("Unable to Launch JVM %d\n",rv);
  else
      printf("Launched JVM! :)\n");
  return env;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  JavaVM *jvm;
  JNIEnv *env;
  env = create_vm(&jvm);
  return 0;
}
```

and my Makefile like

```
all: run

helloWorld.class: helloWorld.java
    /usr/bin/javac helloWorld.java

hello_world: hello_world.c
    gcc -o hello_world \
    -L /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/server/ \
    -ljvm \
    -I /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/include/ \
    -I /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/include/linux/ \
    hello_world.c

run: helloWorld.class hello_world
    export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/server/"
    ./hello_world

clean:
    rm -f helloWorld.class hello_world
```

The resulting output from `make` is

```
/usr/bin/javac helloWorld.java
gcc -o hello_world \
-L /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/server/ \
-ljvm \
-I /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/include/ \
-I /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/include/linux/ \
hello_world.c
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/server/"
./hello_world
./hello_world: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-6-amd64/lib/libjvm.so: no version information available (required by ./hello_world)
Unable to Launch JVM -3
```

The message "Unable to Launch JVM -3" is the program output with the JNI_EVERSION error. I think the line `/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-6-amd64/lib/libjvm.so: no version information available (required by ./hello_world)` gives a hint to the problem, but I do not really understand this issue and when I look into the shared object with `readelf -h /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-6-amd64/lib/libjvm.so` it features a line

```
 Version:                           1 (current)
```

Comment: What part in `java-1.5.0` is unclear? That JVM is 1.5, not 1.8. Why do you keep such an archaic JVM around?

Comment: http://jnicookbook.owsiak.org - take a look there in case you start your jurney with JNI ;)

Answer (score 0):

I finally was able to get it running. Even though I don't know why, the `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH` command in the `Makefile` apparently didn't do its job. Upon checking the content of `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` on the command line I noticed that it contains

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-6-amd64/lib
```

After setting

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/server/"
```

and rerunning `make`, I was able to launch the JVM

Comment: Here's the why: the way it's written in your makefile the "export" line is a separate shell command. And after it finishes, its environment will be gone. To make this work inside the makefile you could either put the "export" outside the target definition or use `env` to set the environment in the same command as the hello_world call. If you want to set the variable only for the "run" target you'd have to duplicate the target name with only the variable declaration `run: export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=...` (will delete my answer because I didn't read the question thoroughl enough)